# How to display a 2D table in java

Tags: java

I try do disply a 2 D table but for some reason I can't, I don't see what i wrote wrong.

This is my code (I am working in vim):

```
            int [][] tab = new int [5][5];

            for (int i= 0; i<tab.length ; i++){
                    for (int j =0; j<tab[i].length; j++){
                            tab[j][i]=i;
                            System.out.println("" + tab[j][i]);
                    }
                    System.out.println("");
            }
    }
```

The result of this code is:

0

0

0

0

1

1

1

1

2

2

2

2

3

3

3

3

4

4

4

4

And i want:

0
0
0
0

1
1
1
1

2
2
2
2

3
3
3
3

4
4
4
4

Can someone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Did you try Googling "print 2d array in java" and click the first result?

Comment: Yes, i did i found an algorithm that does this but the problem is that i don't know what i did wrong in the syntax of this one. Copy pasting an algorithm is easy but I wanted to understand what i did wrong in mine.

Comment: The first example posted is nearly the exact same code as yours with the sole difference of the variable name of the array and the presence of the `ln`.  You need to read the functional code to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the inner loop, replace: -

```
System.out.println("" + tab[j][i]);
```

with: -

```
System.out.print(" " + tab[j][i]);
```

since you want to continue printing in the same row.

Comment: @user1876834. Not possible. Are you sure you are just replacing the `sysout` in the inner loop? Note that you need to change - `System.out.println()` to `System.out.print()`.

Comment: Yes, you were right  that was it, thank you very much for you help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `System.out.println("" + tab[j][i]);`

print a whole line in your output, if you change the

`System.out.println("" + tab[j][i]);`

with

`System.out.print(tab[j][i] + " ");`

adding a blank space, you will print the String in the line but it wont break and
start in a new line. Try what @Rohit Jain post, this is a correct solution...

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the code

```
int [][] tab = new int [5][5];
for (int i= 0; i<tab.length ; i++){
    for (int j =0; j<tab[i].length; j++){
        tab[i][j]=i;
        System.out.print( tab[i][j]+" ");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```

Cause your outer loop run for every row and the inner for every column. So you must use tab[i][j] (the convention is tab[row][col]) to make the code error free. And here in your case you have equal rows & columns. But problem may arise when they are different.

Comment: yes, i tried other value and got this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException                               And i changed the code from this tab[j][i]=i; to this : tab[i][j]=i; and works whatever the values are. Thank you